# Could a "young player" tag be relevant?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Questions like [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/203565/dm-is-taking-too-much-time-in-my-opinion-on-side-missions-should-i-leave), which seems to have been asked by a very young person, would (in my opinion) be better answered by taking this into account (assuming it is indeed a group of ~13yo). Having a specific tag for questions about social interactions in a group of youngsters could help avoiding some answers that don't take it into account.

What do you think, could such a tag be a good idea, is it unnecessary, or would it be problematic?

Comment: Even if it's not helpful in forming answers--tags shouldn't be including info that's not reflected in the post, anyway--I like it (personally) for browsing purposes :thumbsup:

Answer (score 10):

We already have this, I think! We currently have [kids](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kids) and the much less used [teenagers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teenagers), both covering real life social situations involving youngsters and slightly-less-youngsters. We can use the second one here if their age feels materially relevant to the question.

I'm not sure this particular question is about teenagers though; [this comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/203565/dm-is-taking-too-much-time-in-my-opinion-on-side-missions-should-i-leave#comment556983_203565) would seem to clarify that the *characters* are the ones being described as teenagers, not the players, which these tags we're discussing wouldn't be for. We might not know the age of the author.